# How to get area code of location by the postalcode/zipcode?

Tags: php, api

I am working on apps payment system where I have to apply some  canadian GST and HST tax on payment by zipcode. Because my shipping method calculating shipping charge by zipcode.
for example Manitobo have GST 5%, while Ontario have HST 13%.
So how can I look up for areacode or state name, or city name by the zipcode.
If I can get areacode or state name by zipcode then I can make this type of condition to apply tax.

```
if($statename=="Ontario")
{
//apply HST 13%
}
```

Please suggest me any idea, any api to get solved my problems

Thanks...

Comment: You should use a database, either connecting to it via http/https or downloading it onto the server (auto or not) and querying it from there. There may be some algorithm associated with zip codes I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GeoCoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1)

For example, to lookup zip 77379 use a request like this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77379&sensor=true

Comment: I dont think, but still you can check by testing with your zipcode

Comment: yes it is working, but I was looking for area code too.

Comment: yes, for example monitobo have area code 204, while it has number of 453 zipcode or postal code for its locations